# 3D map with OSM2World

Tags: openstreetmap, leaflet, 3d

I want to create a 3d map and have found the [osm2world converter](http://osm2world.org/).
But i do not understand whether I can use it to convert the whole world map from 2d to 3d, for example on 17th and 18th zoom levels, so that when the zoom is below 17 or 18 I see a 2d map, but it switches to 3d at zoom level 17.  Alternatively it could switch to a 3d map using a button.

I am using osm, leaflet, extjs4 on the client.  On the server I am using pyramid framework.

Can anybody help me find out how to create such a mechanism?

Comment: Welcome.  Please take the tour here:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour.  Also, please edit your question to include what you have tried and what you are having issues with.

Comment: You can render whatever tiles and zoom level you want. Making them available via Leaflet is only a matter of configuration.

Comment: @scai i don`t understand how to do that, there aren`t much docs on their website...

Answer (score 1):

Follow this instructions: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/3D_animation (not requiring Blender)

Rendering the whole planet will consume a lot of ressources and isn't available even for maps.osm2world.org